# RedirectToAction async?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I just wrote a controller ThingController with an ListThings action and a Add10Things action.
The Add10Things action inserts 10 Things in database (via Entity) and RedirectToAction("ListThings").

My problem is that ListThings is called before inserting completes. 
I can't see the point since I don't use async controllers.

Here my code :

```
public ActionResult ListThings()
 {
    return View();
 }

 public ActionResult Add10Things()
 {
    using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thing thing = new Thing();
            context.Things.Add(thing);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("ListThings");
 }
```

I use the following javascript for the call : `window.location = "/Add10Things";` .

Comment: It shouldn't. `SaveChanges` is synchronous. Try to set some breakpoints and step through your action, make sure that it is really getting called before it completed. Also, make sure that you are not redirecting at client-side (JS) or wherever else.

Comment: Can you move the `context.SaveChanges();` out of the `foreach` loop. You only need to call it once.

Comment: I updated my question. Hope it helps!

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev You were right! I use a jquery .click on my html link to call my action but I forgot to disable the link with a return false... My bad. Thanks a lot !